# What's the Segulah that one says to repel flies, bees, etc.?

Tags: segulah

A few years ago I heard a girl say just a couple words as a Segulah to repel some hornet bothering her (and it actually worked).

I'm pretty sure this wasn't something she made up, as I've heard this Segulah before. IIRC, it's about 2 or 3 words tops.

And it might be linked to a discussion in the Talmud talking about the 10 Miracles that happened in the Beit HaMikdash, as one of which was that there were no flies or other bugs flying around despite all the sacrifices going on.

So by any chance, does anyone remember about this Segula?
Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Comment: It might have to do with the Mishnah that says that "no fly was seen in the slaughterhouse" [(Avos 5:5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.5?lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en)

Comment: The best segulo is to ask Hashem to get rid of them

Comment: Might also be interesting: וגם את הצרעה.  מלמד שהצרעה עברה עמהם בירדן, וכל אותם אורבים שהיו מטמינים עצמם במערות כדי להרוג, היתה הצרעה נכנסת לשם ומכה אותם בעיניהם והיו מתים:

Comment: Also, maybe it is in the sefer סגולות ישראל by ליפשיץ, שבתי בן יעקב יצחק?

Comment: @Shmuel This most likely be it indeed! (even though I remember being less than 3-4 words, but I might be wrong).

So for other people reading this, here's the whole passuk goes like this:
"לֹא נִרְאָה זְבוּב בְּבֵית הַמִּטְבָּחַיִם" / Lo nireah zvouv beveit hamitba'haim
 - Pirkei Avot 5:5

Thanks so much for your answer and the Sefaria reference!! (also, will look up the other 2 references you suggested, thanks for these as well!)

Comment: Bug spray works as a regular to keep bugs away

Answer (score 3):

[Rav Shraga Kallus](https://www.thesecondsederkollel.com/) (16:00) [said](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=252842) in passing that in order to keep bees away, he has a mesorah from the heim to say, "*bee bee gei avek ich bin a kin frum avraham avinu*."

Comment: Nice find. Interesting why telling this would serve as a segulah.

Comment: Thanks for this gem! That sounds closer to what I've heard actually... But who's the "Heim" ?

Comment: @Zacchino Rav Kallus is from New York, so he may be referring to "word on the streets of New York."

Comment: Got it. And thanks again! Wait, is that segulah in Yiddish? Cuz there’s a couple words I don’t get if it’s in Hebrew or Aramaic…

Comment: @Zacchino Yes, this is mostly Yiddish - loosely translated as, "Bee, bee, go away, I am a descendant of Avraham Avinu."

Comment: Ich bin a Kind fun... would be the correct pronunciation

Comment: Okay, here's my translation: Ich bin a Kind, Cuddly, (and according to my friends, Fun) Frum... Son of (name dropping incoming) Avraham Avinou... So c'mon Bee, I'M WALKING HEEEARE!!